# EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsertAsync giving issues when I try create a Identity user

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am busy merging two projects and with that there are certain methods that I now have to use. When I am creating a new user it fails complaining about Primary key constrains. The weird thing is that the primary key is in a different table from the one that it is complaining about. So my thinking is that it has to do with EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsertAsync(Third party tool by borisdj) and how it saves and UserManager.CreateAsync and how it saves.

This is the error that I am getting:

> Innermost exception    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException :
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.UserDetail'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserDetail'.

I have a method with this if statement:

```
if (await CreateUser.CreateUserDetailAsync(model))
{
    await CreateAccountUser(model.Email, model.Password, model.Role, model.Fullname);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "ShowUser");
}
```

I get the error in the CreateAccountUser user method but it complains about the table in CreateUser.CreateUserDetailAsync.

Th error complains about my UserDetail here is how this is saved. This part works because even with the error, the data get saved to the database.

```
private async Task<boolean> CreateUserDetailAsync(_Models.Settings.User user)
{
    var userDetail = new UserDetail
    {
        Code = user.ERPCode,
        Email = user.Email,
        Name = user.Name,
        Surname = user.Surname
    };

    //Create the 
    await UserDetail.BulkInsertAsync(new List<UserDetail>{userDetail});
    return true;
}
```

This is my method for bulk inserts using EFCore.BulkExtensions.BulkInsertAsync:

```
public Task BulkInsertAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    if (entities == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

    foreach (var item in entities)
    {
        //Attempt to set the Create value of the entity
        var created = typeof(T).GetProperty("Created");
        if (created == null) created = typeof(T).GetProperty("CreatedOn");

        created?.SetValue(item, DateTime.Now, null);

        //Attempt to set the Modified value of the entity
        var modified = typeof(T).GetProperty("Modified");
        if (modified == null) modified = typeof(T).GetProperty("ModifiedOn");

        modified?.SetValue(item, DateTime.Now, null);

        Entities.Add(item);
    }

    return Throw(Db).BulkInsertAsync(entities.ToList());
}
```

I am including this code just for clarity:

```
private static DbContext Throw(IDataContext context) => context as DbContext;
```

Then when I get to this method, it fails on await UserManager.CreateAsync.
private async Task CreateAccountUser(string email, string password, string role,

```
string userFullName = null)
{
    //Register User with identity
    var accountUser = new Core.Data.Models.User();
    accountUser.Email = accountUser.UserName = email;

    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(accountUser, password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are no linking between my User and UserDetail, they are completely separate.

Comment: EF Core has no such `BulkInsertAsync` method. You're using a third party extension, one that actually converts the objects to a DataTable or DbDataReader and calls SqlBulkCopy. You could do the same if not better, by using FastMember's ObjectReader and the SqlBulkCopy class directly

Comment: What are you trying to do? What error do you get? BULK INSERT has nothing to do with relations and makes sense only if you need to insert many hundreds if not thousands or rows. Otherwise, a plain old `SaveChanges` will persist all changes in a single transaction, *and* take care of relations between objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes it is a third party tool. I don't have time for a rewrite at this point.

Comment: `Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserDetail'.` that error is clear - you tried to insert duplicate records. `There are no linking between my User and UserDetail, they are completely separate.` are you sure? What is the primary key of `UserDetail`? is it `Email` perhaps?

Comment: `I don't have time for a rewrite at this point.` you're talking about [these 4 lines](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader). Right now you don't understand what that method is doing, and clearly it's failing. Perhaps it's trying to insert related entities, causing duplicates where you didn't expect it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I can see that, but I am only saving it once with the bulkinsert method. Then when the UserManager.CreateAsync fires it tries to save it again. Or at least that  is what I think is going on

Comment: Without the tables and classes one can only guess what's going on. What do your classes and tables look like? What do they contain right before the error? What are the primary keys ? Is UserManager the ASP.NET Core user manager class? Have you customized the existing User class perhaps? Does *that* class have anything to do with `UserDetails`?

Comment: You're only inserting a single `UserDetail` instance. Why are you trying to use BULK INSERT? This is actually *slower* than a plain old INSERT. If you let EF Core do its job it will persist all the changes in the entities it tracks in a single transaction. If you create a new `ApplicationUser` that has a `UserDetails` property, EF Core will generate INSERTs for both objects in the proper order